# Where do I upload a file for localhost to?

Tags: localhost

I have installed XAMPP on my system (Windows XP Service Pack 3) and I have it all running, but I cannot find where to put the files to go to for localhost. Let's say I'm making a website on my localhost. What directory do I put those files in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Per the XAMPP website -- [Question 2: Where should I place my web content?](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1168)

> The main directory for all WWW documents is \xampp\htdocs. If you put
>   a file "test.html" in this directory, you can access it with the URI
>   "http://localhost/test.html".

Comment: So let's say I created a folder, then I put a test page in there, could I do http://localhost/folder/test.html?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.

Comment: You may [check this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem..